# Calisthenics how many skills?

Tags: exercise, training, bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics

Most people suggest to train one skill at once, but wouldn't  it work just fine by doing one skill per bodypart?

Training multiple  skills at once

Hamstrings= Nordic curls
Quadriceps= Matrix squat

Or

First learning the nordic curl and then the matrix squat and so on.

Which is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, welcome to fitness.SE!

These two exercises in your example **you can indeed learn at the same time**. These are mainly moves of pure power.

When people talk about learning one or two skills at the same time, they are mainly talking about more advanced types of calisthenic exercises. Things like handstands, planches, front levers. These don't just require a lot of power, they are also all about technique and proper form.

If you are still learning a handstand and you also start trying for example a planche, it will most likely hurt the progress you'll make on the handstand.

If you want to learn more advanced calisthenics, **aim to learn about 2 to 3 moves a year and really master** them before moving on to the next.

If you have any other questions, let me know in the comments.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Uhm, thanks... do things like hefesto and one arm muscle ups count as pure power moves?

Comment: If you can do explosive pull-ups and high pull-ups, learning a muscle-up mainly is a matter of learning the technique of the transition from pull-up to straight bar dip. Hefesto is a mix of the two, but it definitely requires a lot of power to do!